# database sql join question

Tags: sql

i have 2 tables called

- Location (id, name)
- Person (id, name, location_id)

A person has a location Id which joins these tables . .  i would like a SQL query that gives me each location and the count of person table for that id.

i could do something like this and then add up the records in code but i want to find out a way that i only get one row per region with count of people in that region

```
SELECT l.*, r.id from Location l
inner join Person r
on r.location_id = l.id 
order by l.name asc
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use aggregates and the GROUP BY clause

```
   SELECT l.id, l.name, count(r.id)    
   FROM  Location l    
   INNER JOIN Person r on r.location_id = l.id    
   GROUP BY l.id., l.name    
   ORDER BY l.name asc
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
  Select L.Name, Count(*) PersonsCount
  From Location L 
    Join Person P On P.Location_Id = L.Id
  Group By L.Name
```

or if you want to see Locations with zero counts,

```
  Select L.Name, Count(*) PersonsCount
  From Location L 
    Left Join Person P On P.Location_Id = L.Id
  Group By L.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT lo.name, COUNT(*)
    FROM LOCATION lo
    JOIN PERSON p ON p.location_id = lo.id
GROUP BY lo.name
ORDER BY lo.name
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

select count(*), Location.name, Location.id from Location, Person where Person.location_id = Location.id group by Location.id